# How do we run some OS command when Rails is starting?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano

I need to run a command after or before starting Rails. It will start a server on port 9292 so my chat app will work.

This command should preferably be executed automatically with Rails (on production and development).

How do we do that in Rails 4?

Is Capistrano the only option? Can we schedule it to be executed when Rails starts?

Answer (score 2):

Use capistrano and forman or systemd to manage your chat server instance, like, for example you would do for sidekiq.

A good start would be : http://anlek.com/2015/01/using-foreman-with-upstart-capistrano/

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options that I know of if you don't want to use Capistrano.  In your config/application.rb

```
config.after_initialize do
    # ....
end
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html

or you can write a custom initializer that is run with on_server_start event.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I don't think it's a good idea : In production, you certainly have several instances running. So it would try to start several time the chat server

Comment: That is a good point and I agree that Capistrano is the correct way to do this.  That said it seems like Victor didn't want to go the capistrano route for some reason.  if you use an after_initialize you could do a check to see if your server was running before actually starting the server which would solve the multiple instance problem.

Comment: On a real production environment, your answer is a no go. How would you restart the chat server if it crash ?

Comment: Full disclosure: Deployment is not my strong Suite or even something I deal with on the regular.  I would say from the sound of things Fred is more knowledgeable on this topic so I will defer to him.

Answer (score -1):

There's a whole section of `config/` intended for startup behavior: `config/initializers/`.  If you need to do anything as part of the startup of your app, you can create an initializer file here, and it will automatically get run as Rails starts.

To do this, simply create a new file: `config/initializers/chat_app.rb`:

```
# This file will start and establish an initial connection to the chat app
`chat-app --some-arg`  # <== The chat app
```

We use this for various startup and system sanity checks for the application.  It's independent of your deployment, so if you need it for other deployment purposes, creating a Capistrano (or even Rake) task is the better option.